# iTunes Connect, Testflight sent confusing names on invite email

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Having a app ready to publish the internal testers are receiving this confusing invite email.

The subject has a name misspeled that we have entered by mistake on the past.

The message has the correct name (the same that we can see on itunesconnect)

Seems like the subject is wrong but, there is any way to confirm this or have anyone experimented this issue before?

Comment: Ok, so whats your problem except that the name in the mail is misspelled?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the name that is going to appear on the App Store is going to be the one that we chose last

Comment: Internal Testers don't show up in the AppStore at all...

Comment: I understand, but we are going to push live and maybe the name that will appear is the misspelled one, I understand that seems like this is a problem with testflight mail rather than the app name on the store but maybe someone can confirm

Comment: You mean the App's name is misspelled?

Comment: Your app's name will be displayed as it is under MyApps.

Comment: Will move forward assuming this and post an answer when accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's name will be displayed as it is under MyApps. No need to worry. Probably just some bug I guess.

Also, I'd recommend to set the release settings to *Developer Release* instead automatic so you'll see the final name just before it's release.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the automatic release removal suggestion